# Obtener los registros que se han actualizado

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

buen día. Tengo el siguiente caso: necesito obtener los registros más nuevos de una serie de registros. Me explico, tengo una tabla de Históricos de Citas para un médico, en ésta tabla se almacenan las horas de las citas "Hora Original de Cita"(Horario para el cual se programó la cita), "Hora de Cita actualizada"(Horario que quedó programada la cita después de una actualización), "Hora de Actualización"(Hora en que se registró la actualización en sistema) y un Estatus de la misma(Agendada, Cancelada, Atendida, Reagendada)

[image: Ver imagen de tabla ejemplo]

De la tabla que coloco necesito obtener los registros marcados en rojo.

Tengo también una tabla de Clientes que tiene como relación con el Histórico el ID de CLiente.

Éste es el código que estoy usando:

```
WITH Consulta as
    (
    SELECT
      Cons.CitaID,
      Cons.InterfaceID,
      Cons.DrName,
      Cons.DrLastName,
      Cons.Aviso,
      Cons.CreationDate,
      Cons.ClientID,
      Cons.SucursalID,
      Cons.StatusID,
      Cons.AppointmentDate,
      ConsHist.UpdateDate
    FROM doc.DrCita as Cons
    INNER JOIN doc.HistDrCita as ConsHist
    ON Cons.InterfaceID = ConsHist.InterfaceID
    AND Cons.AppointmentDate = ConsHist.AppointmentDate ),
    CitasMedico as (
    SELECT   
      doc.Client.ClientName,
      doc.Client.ClientLastName,
      doc.Client.PhoneNumber,
      Consulta.InterfaceID,
      Consulta.DrName,
      Consulta.DrLastName,
      FORMAT( Consulta.AppointmentDate, 'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss') AppointmentDate, 
      doc.HistAppointment.StatusID,
      Consulta.Aviso,
      Sucursal.UnidadID,
      Sucursal.Name,
      FORMAT( Consulta.CreationDate, 'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss') CreationDate,
      doc.CitaStatus.StatusName,
      FORMAT( Consulta.UpdateDate, 'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss') UpdateDate
    FROM Consulta
    INNER JOIN doc.Client
      ON Consulta.ClientID = doc.Client.ClientID
    INNER JOIN doc.Sucursal AS CitSucursal
      ON Consulta.SucursalID = CitSucursal.SucursalID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN doc.AppointmentStatus
      ON Consulta.StatusID = doc.CitaStatus.StatusID
      )

Select * FROM CitasMedico
```

Comment: has hecho alguna prueba? Edita tu pregunta para añadir el código que hayas probado delas consultas que comentas para poder guiarnos mejor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías considerar utilizar la función [RANK](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/rank-transact-sql).

Por ejemplo:

```
CREATE TABLE TABLA (
    ID INT,
    FECHA TIME
)

INSERT INTO TABLA VALUES 
(22, '11:30'), (22, '12:30'), (22, '16:00')
,(23, '14:30'), (23, '17:30')
,(24, '13:50'), (24, '15:00'), (24, '16:00'), (24, '19:00')
,(25, NULL)

SELECT
    ID,
    FECHA
FROM (
    SELECT
        ID,
        FECHA,
        RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY FECHA DESC) RANK
    FROM TABLA    
) X
WHERE X.RANK = 1
```

[**DEMO**](http://rextester.com/RREJ48115)

---

Para tu consulta:

```
WITH Consulta as
(
    SELECT
        Cons.CitaID,
        Cons.InterfaceID,
        Cons.DrName,
        Cons.DrLastName,
        Cons.Aviso,
        Cons.CreationDate,
        Cons.ClientID,
        Cons.SucursalID,
        Cons.StatusID,
        Cons.AppointmentDate,
        ConsHist.UpdateDate
    FROM doc.DrCita as Cons
    INNER JOIN doc.HistDrCita as ConsHist
        ON Cons.InterfaceID = ConsHist.InterfaceID
            AND Cons.AppointmentDate = ConsHist.AppointmentDate 
),
CitasMedico as (
    SELECT   
        doc.Client.ClientName,
        doc.Client.ClientLastName,
        doc.Client.PhoneNumber,
        Consulta.InterfaceID,
        Consulta.DrName,
        Consulta.DrLastName,
        FORMAT( Consulta.AppointmentDate, 'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss') AppointmentDate, 
        doc.HistAppointment.StatusID,
        Consulta.Aviso,
        Sucursal.UnidadID,
        Sucursal.Name,
        FORMAT( Consulta.CreationDate, 'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss') CreationDate,
        doc.CitaStatus.StatusName,
        FORMAT( Consulta.UpdateDate, 'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss') UpdateDate,
        RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY doc.Client.ClientID ORDER BY Consulta.UpdateDate DESC) RANK
    FROM Consulta
    INNER JOIN doc.Client
        ON Consulta.ClientID = doc.Client.ClientID
    INNER JOIN doc.Sucursal AS CitSucursal
        ON Consulta.SucursalID = CitSucursal.SucursalID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN doc.AppointmentStatus
        ON Consulta.StatusID = doc.CitaStatus.StatusID
)
Select * 
FROM CitasMedico
WHERE RANK = 1
```

---

**Referencia:**

- [RANK (Transact-SQL)](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/functions/rank-transact-sql)
- [ROW_NUMBER (Transact-SQL)](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql)

Comment: Hola, es verdad, no incluí algo más que pudiera ayudar a explicarme... este es el código que he realizado

Comment: @ESJ acabo de modificar mi respuesta

Comment: Muchas gracias @Davlio por tu ayuda